# How can I Fix "OnPress not working inside a header but works independently "

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am new to react native. I am using react native elements and react native vector icons.
I have an Icon.Button inside my header, I am having a tough time to get it to work. However, when I use the component just by itself, it works as expected

this is my ButtonTest.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert } from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

export default class ButtonTest extends Component {
  onPress = () => {
    console.log("Button was pressed");
    Alert.alert("Button was pressed");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Icon.Button
          name="rocket"
          size={30}
          color="#FFFF"
          onPress={this.onPress}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is working as expected.

however when I use the same logic in my AppHeader.tsx, it just doesn't work

AppHeader.tsx

```
import { Header } from "react-native-elements";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Alert, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

const AppHeader = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header
        placement="left"
        leftComponent={{ icon: "menu", color: "#fff" }}
        centerComponent={{ text: "MY TITLE", style: { color: "#fff" } }}
        rightComponent={<Rocket />}
      />
      <Rocket />
    </View>
  );
};

class Rocket extends Component {
  onPress = () => {
    console.log("Button was pressed");
    Alert.alert("Button was pressed");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Icon.Button
        name="rocket"
        size={30}
        color="#FFFF"
        onPress={this.onPress}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The app header loads up perfectly fine. However (On simulator) when I try to click it, nothing happens

but if i click the ButtonTest Component, it works perfectly fine. I get the console.log and the alert.

Please help

Comment: did you try to put `<Icon.Button>` inside of a view tag? (in header file)

Comment: Tried that no difference. It still wont work